# Splunk convert extracted field in currently milliseconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: type-conversion, splunk

can anyone provide me with a way to have Splunk convert an extracted field which is currently in milliseconds to HH:MM:SS?

Answer (score 0):

```
...| fieldFormat inSeconds = tostring(inMS/1000,"duration)
```

where inMS is the name of the extracted field
and inSeconds is the result you want

add  `| fields - inMS` to remove the original field