# splunk latest event for each host

Tags: splunk

I am trying to get the latest event timestamp for each host, google search found below:

|metadata type=hosts | table host, lastTime

it seems worked, returned the host and the timestamp, however, the timestamp is an big integer number, how do I convert to local time?

also how do I filter it so it only return certain hosts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time formatting - try this post:  [Splunk convert extracted field in currently milliseconds to HH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828540/splunk-convert-extracted-field-in-currently-milliseconds-to-hhmmss)

For the host search - you should be able to | search host=XXXX